# Metric on function space for Pointwise Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, sequence-of-function

We say that $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that converges pointwise to $f\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ if, for any $x$ in $[a,b]$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$.

In this definition we talked about “convergence” without speaking of metric. Is there any metric (or topology) on space of functions (or continuous functions) from $[a,b]$ into $\mathbb{R}$ which leads to this convergence?

Comment: There is no metric in this case. There is a topology, however. This topology is sometimes just called the topology of pointwise convergence. Other times it is called the product topology. The latter makes sense because this space can be identified with the uncountable product: $$\prod_{x \in [a,b]} \mathbb{R}_x$$ where each $\mathbb{R}_x$ is a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology. We can more generally define the product topology on arbitrary products of topological spaces. It is assembled by identifying a base consisting of products of open sets in the original spaces, and then closin

Comment: No to metric (see http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1951-002-01/S0002-9939-1951-0040647-7/S0002-9939-1951-0040647-7.pdf), yes to topology (weak topology).

Answer (score 3):

There is such a topology, yes. For each $x\in[0,1]$, let $\Bbb R_x=\Bbb R$ and consider the product $\prod_{x\in[0,1]}\Bbb R_x$, endowed with the product topology. Then $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $f$ with respect to this topology if and only if it converges pointwise.

Now, I am going to provide an outline of a proof due to M. K. Fort that no metric can be defined in your space with that property. For more details, see his article [*A note on pointwise convergence*](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1951-002-01/S0002-9939-1951-0040647-7/S0002-9939-1951-0040647-7.pdf). Without loss of generality, we can assume that $[a,b]=[0,1]$. Fort defines a family $\{f_{n,m}\mid n,m\in\Bbb N\}$ of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ into $\Bbb R$. This family is defined in such a way that, for each $n\in\Bbb N$ and each $t\in[0,1]$, $f_{n,m}(t)=0$ for all but three values of $m$. Therefore, for each $t\in[0,1]$ we have $\lim_{m\to\infty}f_{n,m}(t)=0$. In other words, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, the sequence $(f_{n,m})_{m\in\Bbb N}$ converges pointwise to the null function. So, if there was a metric $d$ on $\Bbb R^{[0,1]}$ such that convergence with respect to $d$ would be the same thing as pointwise convergence, we would have $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\lim_{m\to\infty}f_{n,m}=0$ in $\bigl(\Bbb R^{[0,1]},d\bigr)$. Therefore, it is possible to choose integers $N_n$ such that$$m_n>N_n\implies d\left(f_{n,m_n},0\right)<\frac1n.$$So, any sequence $\left(f_{n,m_n}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges pointwise to the null function.

Then Fort shows that this is not possible. It follows from the way that the functions $f_{n,m}$ are defined that, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, there is some closed interval $[a_n,b_n]$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f_{n,m}|_{[a_n,b_n]}=1$ if $m$ is larger than some natural number $m_n$ and that $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]\subset[a_n,b_n]$. But then $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}[a_n,b_n]\ne\emptyset$ and, if $x\in\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}[a_n,b_n]$,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n,m_n}(x)=1\ne0.$$So, the sequence $\left(f_{n,m_n}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ does *not* converge pointwise to the null function.